# how to display last 10 numbers in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table A with two column `(number varchar(600),Date_ varchar(800))`
now i have to display last 10 numbers order by Date_.

```
   SELECT top(10) Number,Date FROM A ORDER BY Date_ DESC,
```

the problem is that for one month its showing result as desired,
but as soon next month start it not showing result as desired

i want the result like this.

```
10,2/2/2016
22,1/2/2016
10,31/1/2016
20,30/1/2016
30,29/1/2016
23,28/1/2016
20,27/1/2016
11,26/1/2016
18,25/1/2016
62,24/1/2016
56,23/1/2016
54,22/1/2016
44,21/1/2016
```

i am getting this result for --/1/2016 month but not for --/2/2016.
so kindly help.

Comment: You should start by changing your table data types into `integer` and `date`

Comment: `"i am getting this result for --/1/2016 month but not for --/2/2016"` - What does that even mean?  What's wrong about the result you're getting?  Note that your data is `varchar` data, so it's going to sort alphabetically.

Comment: change the type of the date column to date instead of varchar and your problem will be solved

Comment: your dates are STRINGS, which mean string sorting rules apply. that means `'19/12/2016' < '19/3/2016'` is TRUE, because the `1` in `12` is SMALLER than `3`.

Comment: If you are going to have dates as strings you need to have them in year-month-day order and zero fill the month and day to 2 digits, but as others have said just change the data type.

Comment: Do you want the 10 numbers that belong to the records with the last 10 dates *in the entire table*, or do you want the 10 numbers that belong to the records with the last 10 dates *in every month that exists in the table*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below script

```
 SELECT top(10) Number,Date 
  FROM A 
  ORDER BY convert(datetime,Date,103) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to/can't change the structure of your table, then you need to use [Parsing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316.aspx).

```
SELECT TOP 10 PARSE(Number AS int) AS Number,
              PARSE(Date AS datetime2) AS Date
FROM A
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

You may need to do a `PARSE` in your `ORDER BY` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small change to your code should fix this

SELECT top(10) Number,Date FROM A **ORDER BY cast(DATE_ as date)** DESC.

Typically dates are stored as numbers in Microsoft world, i.e. 1/1/1900 is 1
1/2/1900 is 2
1/31/1900 is 31 and so on...

So changing your varchar to a date (provided there is no junk in the field) should fix this.